# Is there a distance extending the standard distance with the added requirement that there is a sequences over the set converging to infinity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

We let $\mathfrak{R} = \Bbb{R}^+_0 \cup \{\infty\}$. The question is, can we find some distance function $h$ on $\mathfrak{R}$ which extends the standard Euclidean distance on $\mathbb{R}^+_0$ and also has the property that:

**EDIT:**  $\exists$ $c \in (\mathbb{R}_0^+)^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $c$ converges to infinity with respect to the distance $h$.

Thanks,
Lauren

Comment: You want **all** sequences converges to $\infty$?

Comment: Clearly not: a sequence in $\Bbb R$ that converges in the usual metric to some $a\in\Bbb R$ still converges to $a$ in any metric extending the usual one.

Comment: So $(0, 0, 0, \dots)$ would converge to $\infty$? Nah.

Comment: Yes, ANY $c \in (\Bbb{R}_0^+)^{\Bbb{N}}$ must converge to $\infty$ with respect to this distance $h$, but $h$ must preserve the standard distance (ie. $h(x,y) = | x - y |$)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, I thought that this was a bit of a ridiculous question too but it is one of the questions we have been asked. How would you suggest that I formalise a proof that this cannot be true? What do you think is the easiest way?

Comment: @Lauren: It was getting a little long, so I wrote it up as an answer.

Comment: Some variations on this are true, though. There are metrics that induce the same topology on $\mathbb{R}$ such that all sequences that "diverge to ±$\infty$" (suitably defined) converge to $\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the constant sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ with $x_n=0$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Show that it converges to $0$ in the usual metric, which is trivial, and hence in $h$, since $h$ agrees with the usual one on all the relevant points. Let $r=h(0,\infty)$; clearly we must have $r>0$, or $h$ isn’t a metric. Then the open $h$-ball of radius $r$ centred at $\infty$ contains no term of the sequence, so the sequence cannot converge to $\infty$.

**Added after the question was corrected:** There is no such extension. Suppose that $h$ were such an extension, and let $x=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\in{^{\Bbb N}\Bbb R_{0}^+}$ converge to $\infty$ in the metric $h$. Then $x$ is $h$-Cauchy, so there is an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $h(x_k,x_\ell)<1$ whenever $k,\ell\ge m$. If $x$ is bounded in $\Bbb R_0^+$, it has a subsequence converging in the usual metric and hence in $h$ to some $\alpha\in\Bbb R_0^+$. But this is impossible: in $h$ every subsequence of $x$ converges to $\infty$. Thus, $x$ must be unbounded, and there is therefore an $n>m$ such that $x_n\ge x_m+1$. But then $h(x_n,x_m)=|x_n-x_m|\ge 1$, contradicting the choice of $m$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer yesterday, however, as I thought, there was incorrect phrasing in the original question. We want to show existence only, so, I updated the OP with the fixed question.

Comment: @Lauren: I’ve added an answer to that question.

Comment: Perfect Brian, thanks very much, that argument seems very intuitive and straightforward. So, the main things going on here are: we are using the fact that all real sequences which converge are Cauchy (and vice versa) and then making a contradiction so that the sequence isn't Cauchy, implying it doesn't converge?

Comment: @Lauren: You’re welcome. All we actually need is that in any metric a convergent sequence is always Cauchy, and that all of its subsequences have the same limit.